# Prove\disprove that if $X \vdash \alpha$ or $Y \vdash \alpha$ then $X\cup Y \vdash \alpha$

Tags: logic

I found this statement at my of my books,

> if $X \vdash \alpha$ or $Y \vdash \alpha$ then $X\cup Y \vdash \alpha$

Now, I want to prove it but I don't really know how, may be I will prove it with contrapositive?

so if $X\cup Y \nvdash \alpha$ then $X \nvdash \alpha$ and $Y \nvdash \alpha$

How can I continue from here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to write down the definition of $\vdash$, before you go on. Contraposition may lead you astray in this case.

Comment: As @user319052 says. I wouldn't pursue contraposition. There's a simple, constructive proof that falls out of the definition of $\vdash$.